# Move Mini Cart - Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to move the cart next to the search bar here but it isn't working.

[image]

A user has asked the same question here:

[Move Mini Cart (Magento 2)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201546/move-mini-cart-magento-2)

When I put in

```
<move element="minicart" destination="header.container" before="-" />
```

or

```
    <move element="minicart" destination="header.panel" after="top.search" />
```

My cart ends up in the top right corner on the first code and on the second one, it disappears.

Code:

[image: code]

I have moved my search bar by adding the below to default.xml:

```
        <move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
```

Comment: The minicart is not completely gone. Is this what you want?

Comment: @BareFeet No, I want to move the cart next to the search bar as shown in the first picture. The only way I can move it with CSS is by adding margin-right but this throws out the 'drop down' that appears when you click it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below code

```
<move element="minicart" destination="header-wrapper" after="top.search"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it just stays in the same place as shown in the 1st picture.

Comment: Then you should manage using css because layout was correct I think

Comment: The cart has display: inline-block; and vertical-align: top; set to it in CSS but when removing these options and adding float: left; it does nothing.. the only way I can move it is by using margin-right but this messes up the drop down that appears when you click the cart.

Comment: Could you please try  float:right;

Comment: I've managed to do it.. your code above is correct and I had to apply float: left; - I was applying the CSS to the wrong class, the correct one is: .minicart-wrapper